# How can I use a variable declared in another function in a function outside it?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to change text in a div element to a string of text obtained from a json file when a button is clicked.

I'm reading from my json file declaring the information as data. I then wanted to run a function that is activated when buttons on my page are clicked to change the text to whatever index the button id corresponds to.

The json file just has an "events" array and each object has a "name" and "text". The name is irrelevant and is only there for me to distinguish what each one is really.

Each button in the html file has an individual id that starts from 1 and goes up for each button (there is no id 0 button because I have the first object in the array as a test in the json with nothing of value in it) and they also have an onclick event that triggers the changeText() function.

So my goal is to check the id of the button that is clicked and then get the "text" string from the json and change the innerHTML of the text-area div element into that.

This is the js code:

```
function loadData() {
    fetch('../text/events.json')
        .then(info => {
            return info.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        })
        .then(
            data => {
                var txt = document.getElementById("text-area");
                var btnID = this.id;

                txt.innerHTML = data.events[btnID].text;
            }
        )
}
```

Here is an example of one of the buttons I'm using:
`<button class="tl-btn btn-right" onclick="loadData()" id="2" style="margin-top: 10px">test1</button>`

Here is the json file:

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "name": "test-name",
            "text": "test-text"
        },
        {
            "name": "test-name1",
            "text": "test-text1"
        },
        {
            "name": "test-name2",
            "text": "test-text2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I keep getting: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'events' of undefined
    at changeText (main.js:18)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:21)

I'm honestly not sure what the problem is. The json file reads perfectly since the console displays the logged data obtained from it.

I'm really sorry if I sound really confusing, please feel free to ask me anything that isn't clear and I look forward to any help.

Thank you! :D

**EDIT 1**: I changed some of the code based on the suggestions below and I'm now getting a different error:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined

**Edit 2**: I found the problem with the code being that it couldn't read the format of the json so I just had to parse it like this:

```
.then(data => {
        var txt = document.getElementById("text-area");

        txt.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data.events[0].text).slice(1,-1)
    })
```

The slice cleans up the quotation marks.

Comment: You don't need the parenthesis after `loadData` in this line `window.addEventListener('load', loadData())` - that will immediately invoke the function

Comment: Keep in mind that "fetch" goes after resources asynchronously, so you need to change the text and call changeText(data) only when you get a response back inside your "then". Because it is asynchronous, your code doesn't stop at that point to wait for something to be returned, like you did with "return data".

Comment: I've never heard of asynchronous calls before, I only used return because I was looking at other questions that were similar to mine before using return was suggested in the answer. I'll read up on the asynchronous calls though. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `changeText` into your callback with the data:

```
window.addEventListener('load', loadData);

function changeText(data) {
    var txt = document.getElementById("text-area");
    var btnID = this.id;

    txt.innerHTML = data.events[btnID].text;
}

function loadData() {
    fetch('../text/events.json')
        .then(info => {
            return info.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            changeText(data);
            return data;
        })
}
```

Comment: I tried that but then the chrome console says that changeText() is not defined.

Comment: @MikeHanna edited the answer. Try changing the function declaration order.

Comment: @Clarity the function declaration order is irrelevant - they would both be visible at any point during the execution due to hoisting.

Comment: I tried that but it still resulted in an Uncaught TypeError :(

Comment: @VLAZ that's what I was thinking but the error doesn't make sense there.

Comment: @MikeHanna did you actually remove function invocation when assigning event listener, you need to do this: `window.addEventListener('load', loadData)`. Note removed braces from `loadData`.

Comment: Yeah I did that.

Comment: Then I think the issue is on some other parts of your code, that you didn't show.

Comment: This is all my js code, the only other error I get is a: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :   for line 2 of the json file where I declare "events" but I assumed it was not important.

Comment: @MikeHanna that is actually important since you can't declare variables in json files.

Comment: I'm really sorry for the bother, I'll just show you what my json looks like before I confuse you any further.